# entity framework 4 function imports stored proc complex type return no column

Tags: sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, complextype

I have imported a SP to Entity Entity Data Model and added it to the function imports.

I can get column information and create a complex type `GetErrorCheckJobs_Result`.

However, after i added a parameter onto the sp and try to update(refresh,delete and add back) the function import, it failed to retrieve column information.

It says: `the selected stored procedure returns no columns`

I have searched various solutions online and have

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF

SET FMTONLY OFF
```

at the beginning of my SP but still no luck.

Here is my sp:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[s_GetErrorCheckJobs]
                        @ErrorChecked bit

as
begin
 SET NOCOUNT OFF
 SET FMTONLY OFF


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempColumns') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempColumns


create table #TempColumns 
(
        AssetID int
        ,JobReference varchar(30)
        ,DetailCode varchar(4)

        ,Lamp varchar(255)
        ,pLamp varchar(255)

        ,LuminaireType varchar(255)
        ,pLuminaireType varchar(255)

        ,ColumnStyle varchar(255)
        ,pColumnStyle varchar(255)

        ,ColumnHeight varchar(255)
        ,pColumnHeight varchar(255)

        ,ColumnOutreach varchar(255)
        ,pColumnOutreach varchar(255)
)


//Insert into #TempColumns 
//update #TempColumns 

select 
v.JobId
,v.JobReference
,v.ErrorChecked
,v.WASPAssetId
,v.StreetlightId
,v.DateReceived
,v.DateDueActual
,v.DateCompleted
,v.ActivityCodeIdActual
,v.CrewId
,v.JobCause
,v.Suburb
,v.Address
,v.Problem
,v.SpecialInstructions
,v.Notes

,t.Lamp
        ,t.pLamp

        ,t.LuminaireType 
        ,t.pLuminaireType

        ,t.ColumnStyle 
        ,t.pColumnStyle

        ,t.ColumnHeight 
        ,t.pColumnHeight

        ,t.ColumnOutreach 
        ,t.pColumnOutreach

         from v_errorcheck_jobs v
join #TempColumns t on t.jobreference = v.jobreference and t.assetid = v.waspassetid
where v.ErrorChecked = @ErrorChecked

end
```

any help appreciate, thanks

Comment: did you try blowing away the function import and re-adding it?

Comment: When this happens normally the only way to fix it is to go into the xml of the edmx and remove all traces of your complex object as well as our function import and the mapping, I normally start with the Complex Type and do a find on the name and then on the function import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

duplicated the sp and renamed it 
and did the whole process again

Comment: I ran into this as well. The most reliable thing I've found to always work it to simply put a 'data contract' (a bogus select statement) into the top of the SPROC inside a condition that will never evaluate true, as provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16594665/237723

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late, but you have to turn **NOCOUNT** back on before the **"real"** select, so that it can use that to create your projection list.